# Excel VBA: Delete Rows in a Column based on a Range of Cells in another Column

Tags: vba, excel

[Excel Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqiIF.png)

I have the above Excel sheet and have been trying to use VBA to delete rows based on the values in column B, provided they match values currently residing in column C. I'm a coding novice and have so far only gotten to a point of managing to delete a row by selecting a single cell in column C (There was a row containing the value *331013* in column B and I managed to delete it by selecting the cell in column C with that that value (currently the first row) and it was deleted.

What I want to do is to select the entire range of values in column C so I can delete all of the matching values in column B in a single batch.

The following is what I've managed so far based on a lot of googling, it is working with just one selection, but when I manually select more than 1 row it just deletes the corresponding value of the first selection and if I select the entire column range I get a mismatch error. And I've also previously gotten a stack overflow error

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim DeleteRng As Range
Dim DeleteStr As Range

xTitleId = "Input"

Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set DeleteStr = Application.Selection

Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("delete range :", xTitleId, DeleteStr.Address, Type:=8)
For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
        If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRng = rng
        Else
            Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate whatever input can be given.

Comment: I'm honestly sorry but you **absolutely** have to work numerically from the last rfow to the top if you want a clean delete. A union of rows is an option.

Comment: ^^ Meaning loop with a -1 step from last row to first  using a For Loop. Or loop forwards gathering qualifying rows with Union, and if the union is not nothing at the end then delete.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have tried the following and I get a mismatch error

`Sub DeleteRows()
Dim i As Integer
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim DeleteRng As Range
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set DeleteRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set DeleteRng = Application.InputBox("delete range :", xTitleId, DeleteRng.Address, Type:=8)
For i = DeleteRng To 1 Step -1
If IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 2), DeleteRng, 0)) Then
Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i
End Sub`

Comment: Sorry for the above block of text, I just couldn't get the line breaks to work for the life of me. Hope someone can still decipher the changes I made and provide their help